# Как отловить перемещающиеся объекты в браузере

Tags: python, selenium

Есть онлайн игрушка.
При открытии страницы, необходимо, чтобы бот на селениуме отловил бота и кликнул по нему.
Проблема в том, что бот постоянно перемещается
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как поймать моба?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте реализовать что-то подобное, вполне реально, что Вам может потребоваться использовать дополнительные методы и функции для решения этой задачи.

```python
# Импортируйте необходимые библиотеки для работы с
# Selenium WebDriver и элементами страницы
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

# Запустите браузер и откройте страницу со своей игрой
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://example.com")

# Найдите элемент, который нужно отловить. Учитывая, что объект
# постоянно перемещается, то вам может потребоваться
# использовать цикл, чтобы найти его
while True:
    try:
        # Найдите элемент с помощью XPath, CSS-селектора или другого метода
        element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='moving-element']")
        break
    except:
        continue
        
# Как только вы найдете нужный элемент, вы можете использовать
# методы из библиотеки ActionChains, чтобы выполнить
# некоторые действия с этим элементом. Например, вы можете
# использовать метод move_to_element, чтобы переместить
# курсор на элемент, а затем выполнить клик
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element(element).click().perform()

# Завершите работу с браузером
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Не помогло, также пробовал через pyautogui , тоже не ловит